# Pandas dataframe getting specific row and columns

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas dataframe has

```
 FRUIT      DATE  PRICE
 Apple 11/5/2021     10
 Apple 12/5/2021     11
 Apple 13/5/2021     15
Orange 11/5/2021     20
Orange 12/5/2021     29
Orange 13/5/2021     15
Banana 11/5/2021      5
Banana 12/5/2021      7
Banana 13/5/2021      6
```

Data in pandas dataframe
I need data of first two dates of every fruit name like

```
 FRUIT      DATE  PRICE
 Apple 11/5/2021     10
 Apple 12/5/2021     11
Banana 11/5/2021      5
Banana 12/5/2021      7
Orange 11/5/2021     20
Orange 12/5/2021     29
```

I have more than 100 fruit names

How to write condition for filtering the data?

Comment: When asking a question you should include an example of what you have tried so far, if you have not tried anything yet you might need to do some research before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by `DATE` then groupby `FRUIT` and keep 2 first rows of each group:

```
>>> df.sort_values('DATE').groupby('FRUIT').head(2).sort_values('FRUIT')

    FRUIT       DATE  PRICE
0   Apple  11/5/2021     10
1   Apple  12/5/2021     11
6  Banana  11/5/2021      5
7  Banana  12/5/2021      7
3  Orange  11/5/2021     20
4  Orange  12/5/2021     29
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806930/selecting-rows-and-columns-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304235/substracting-values-from-two-different-pandas-dataframes-based-on-same-row-value

Comment: Edited my question, pls go through it

Comment: @hariprasad. I updated my answer.