# selecting rows and columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

pandas dataframe has , number of items selling quantity

```
FRUIT   YESTERDAY    TODAY    TOMORROW
Apple     5           5         3
Apple     3           5         3
Orange    6           9         8
Banana    0           0         0
Grapes    7           7         7
Guava     0           3         3
Mango     2           8         2
Mango     4           4         6
```

The above data is in pandas dataframe , Using IF condition ,
I need data like , after filtering with below conditions
(Cond-1) we have to check any of value of  YESTERDAY , TODAY , TOMORROW are equal to zero then exclude that rows.(cond-1A) also checking if YESTERDAY, TODAY, TOMORROW all have same values then exclude such rows. (Like , Excluding Grapes  7   7  7).
(Cond-2) after filtering data with cond-1 , we have check condition for YESTERDAY and TODAY are equal then get such rows
(cond-3) we have to check condition for YESTERDAY and TOMORROW are equal then display such rows

**OUTPUT :**

YESTERDAY and TODAY Equal are

```
FRUIT   YESTERDAY   TODAY   TOMORROW
Apple       5         5       3
Mango       4         4       6
```

YESTERDAY and TOMORROW are Equal

```
FRUIT      YESTERDAY    TODAY   TOMORROW
Apple        3           5         3
Mango        2           8         2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a boolean mask to filter your dataframe:

```
cols = ['YESTERDAY', 'TODAY', 'TOMORROW']
mask = df[cols].ne(0).all(1) & df[cols].std(axis=1).ne(0)
out = df[mask]
```

Mask detail:

- `df[cols].ne(0).all(1)` keep rows which have no 0 in their columns.
- `df[cols].std(axis=1).ne(0)` keep rows which have at least one different value in their columns . A standard deviation of 0 means all values are equals (7, 7, 7).

First output:

```
>>> out.loc[out['YESTERDAY'] == out['TODAY']]
   FRUIT  YESTERDAY  TODAY  TOMORROW
0  Apple          5      5         3
7  Mango          4      4         6
```

Second output:

```
>>> out.loc[out['YESTERDAY'] == out['TOMORROW']]
   FRUIT  YESTERDAY  TODAY  TOMORROW
1  Apple          3      5         3
6  Mango          2      8         2
```

Comment: @hariprasad. I removed this value 7 7 7 using the standard deviation. Can you check the output please?

Comment: not working for me , can't we write df['YESTERDAY','TODAY','TOMORROW']  instead of df[cols]  .   as the data in dataframe is reading  from csv file .

Comment: You can write `df[['YESTERDAY','TODAY','TOMORROW']]` (double square brackets). And what's wrong with the solution?

Comment: Thanks working, I am accepting your answer

Comment: pls look into this question             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479119/calculating-groupby-sum-of-values-on-column-based-on-string-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pd.DataFrame.query` after masking where dataframe equals to zero:

```
df.mask(df == 0).query('YESTERDAY == TOMORROW')
```

Output:

```
    FRUIT  YESTERDAY  TODAY  TOMORROW
1   Apple        3.0    5.0       3.0
4  Grapes        7.0    7.0       7.0
6   Mango        2.0    8.0       2.0
```

And,

```
df.mask(df == 0).query('YESTERDAY == TODAY')
```

Output:

```
    FRUIT  YESTERDAY  TODAY  TOMORROW
0   Apple        5.0    5.0       3.0
4  Grapes        7.0    7.0       7.0
7   Mango        4.0    4.0       6.0
```

Comment: Query looks clean in such scenarios, and even implementing it via a user defined function makes it more robust and flexible for multiple scenarios.

Comment: @Scott Boston  can we do the above  with IF condition

Comment: @ScottBoston if possible can we eliminate rows which has same values for YESTERDAY,TODAY and  TOMORROW i.e., eliminating GRAPE  7   7   7    from above two outputs

Comment: pls look into this question      
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479119/calculating-groupby-sum-of-values-on-column-based-on-string-in-pandas