# Substracting values from two different pandas dataframes based on same row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data of two dataframes
First dataframe:

```
Name    price  date
Apple    25   23-9-2021
Orange   35   23-9-2021
Banana   15   23-9-2021
Gauva    10   23-9-2021
Grapes   5    23-9-2021
Sapota   15   22-9-2021
Papaya   33   21-9-2021
Apple    20   23-9-2021
Orange   30   23-9-2021
Banana   10   23-9-2021
Gauva    10   23-9-2021
Grapes   5    23-9-2021
Apple    15   23-9-2021
Orange   25   23-9-2021
Banana   25   23-9-2021
Gauva    20   23-9-2021
Grapes   15    23-9-2021
```

Second dataframe:

```
Name   price   date
Apple   80     23-9-2021
Orange  100     23-9-2021
Banana  90     23-9-2021
Gauva   60     23-9-2021
Grapes  45     23-9-2021
```

In first dataframe sum all price values of same fruit name and do substraction i.e.,
I want to substract price value of two dataframes based on row values of same Name and Date and store it into first dataframe

Output: first dataframe

```
Name   price   date
Apple   25     23-9-2021
Orange  35     23-9-2021
Banana  15     23-9-2021
Gauva   10     23-9-2021
Grapes  5      23-9-2021
Sapota  15     22-9-2021
Papaya  33     21-9-2021
Apple    20   23-9-2021
Orange   30   23-9-2021
Banana   10   23-9-2021
Gauva    10   23-9-2021
Grapes   5    23-9-2021
Apple    15   23-9-2021
Orange   25   23-9-2021
Banana   25   23-9-2021
Gauva    20   23-9-2021
Grapes   15    23-9-2021
Apple   20     23-9-2021
Orange  10     23-9-2021
Banana  40     23-9-2021
Gauva   20     23-9-2021
Grapes  15     23-9-2021
```

I have more than hundred of such fruitnames.
I don't know how to do this

Comment: Just a heads up, it's spelled "guava"

Comment: The last row of output dataframe is false. It should be 20 for Grapes.

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_index` instead of `merge`:

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2.set_index(['Name', 'date'])['price']
                         .sub(df1.groupby(['Name', 'date'])['price'].sum())
                         .dropna().reset_index()], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out

      Name  price       date
0    Apple   25.0  23-9-2021
1   Orange   35.0  23-9-2021
2   Banana   15.0  23-9-2021
3    Gauva   10.0  23-9-2021
4   Grapes    5.0  23-9-2021
5   Sapota   15.0  22-9-2021
6   Papaya   33.0  21-9-2021
7    Apple   20.0  23-9-2021
8   Orange   30.0  23-9-2021
9   Banana   10.0  23-9-2021
10   Gauva   10.0  23-9-2021
11  Grapes    5.0  23-9-2021
12   Apple   15.0  23-9-2021
13  Orange   25.0  23-9-2021
14  Banana   25.0  23-9-2021
15   Gauva   20.0  23-9-2021
16  Grapes   15.0  23-9-2021
17   Apple   20.0  23-9-2021
18  Banana   40.0  23-9-2021
19   Gauva   20.0  23-9-2021
20  Grapes   20.0  23-9-2021
21  Orange   10.0  23-9-2021
```

Comment: edited my question pls go through it , sorry for editing my question and late reply. pls  modify code according to question edited.

Comment: not getting correct values after substraction.

Comment: if i have two or more columns in two dataframes like Temperature and Day. then how to print that columns in Output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69682803/comparing-column-values-in-groupby-in-pandas

Answer (score 2):

1. [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both dataframes
2. Find the difference in price
3. [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, how="left", on=["Name", "date"])
df3["price"] = df3["price_x"]-df3["price_y"]

output = pd.concat([df1, df3.drop(["price_x", "price_y"], axis=1)])

>>> output
     Name  price       date
0   Apple     25  23-9-2021
1  Orange     35  23-9-2021
2  Banana     15  23-9-2021
3   Gauva     10  23-9-2021
4  Grapes      5  23-9-2021
5  Sapota     15  22-9-2021
6  Papaya     33  21-9-2021
0   Apple      5  23-9-2021
1  Orange     10  23-9-2021
2  Banana     15  23-9-2021
3   Gauva     10  23-9-2021
4  Grapes     20  23-9-2021
```

Comment: I ran this code because I was confused by the `date` column and it turned out your output wasn't matching what the code was outputting (and also didn't match OP's desired result) so I edited.

Comment: It's just date formatting. Doesn't really affect the code logic

Comment: No, not the formatting -- all of your dates were `23-9-2021` but some of OP's actual dates have `21-` and `22-`. Your output also spelled guava correctly, whereas OP's has a typo.

Comment: Just as a tip, OP's DataFrames are actually copy-paste-able, using `pd.read_clipboard()`. That way you don't have to manually construct the DataFrames, which it seems like is maybe what happened here :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69682803/comparing-column-values-in-groupby-in-pandas